# Synonym for "file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is something that's bugging me for a long time. I'm looking for a proper name to call a model that holds files (for example, a model that manages files to send to clients). Just "File" isn't possible, because it's a reserved word and in some cases "Asset" isn't appropriate either. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: This depends heavily on context; and has no single right answer. Element, Resource..perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

"File" is pretty generic.  Perhaps you can come up with a more specific name that describes what is being saved?  Here are some other words I have used in the past:

Attachment, Document, Photo, Contract, LegalDocument, Template

Comment: Attachment is pretty common, Document a close second, at least in my experience.

Comment: Good stuff people, thanks a lot! FYI: I've used "Download" this time.

Answer (score 0):

How about `FileModel` or `FileClass`...

Answer (score 0):

I think Packet would work well in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Attach` model name for this thing as far as it is really attach :D